# Are there limitations for result array size in codeigniter query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm working with codeigniter and a database. With this method, i have an empty response:

```
public function get_utenti(){
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

But if i add a limit query, as following, this method works fine:

```
public function get_utenti(){
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

PS: Table 'users' contains more than 24000 records. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your php error log. Are you getting a memory exceeded error or maybe a execution time exceeded?

Comment: _PS: Table 'users' contains a lot of records._ Really helpful. Would you like to give us a slightly more useful guess at how many ___a lot___ is

Comment: Lets assume _a lot_ is 1000. Why would you ever want to retrieve all of them, you cannot show all those to a user on a page, there are just to many. If _a lot_ is 100,000 then the senario becomes even sillier.

Comment: Always, **always** limit your queries. Having something that selects the universe from a table is asking for trouble.

Comment: Table has more than 24000 records... I edited now this in my post, excuse me, you are right!

Comment: I look at my php error log and i read this: [05-Sep-2016 11:42:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/masterclub-api-v2/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php on line 168 I suppose that I get a memory exceeded error! Thank you RiggsFolly!